# Wifi communication. Alternative for wifi_comm?

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to establish ad-hoc wifi communication between two Raspberry Pi, both will be running roscore and a full set of applications. I just want to exchange information between them.

I found [wifi_comm](http://wiki.ros.org/wifi_comm) package, it seems to do what I want. However, it seems to be discontinued and a little bit incomplete (not criticizing). Are there any alternative for this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327190/wifi-communication.-alternative-for-wifi_comm?/) by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also do research in this topic. I think http://wiki.ros.org/adhoc_communication is similar and may help you.

---

Originally posted by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) with karma: 272 on 2019-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0